# Is there any way I can duplicate another website using PHP or htaccess.

Tags: php, .htaccess, a-records

I'm moving a website to a new server since I've lost the password of the old one and there is no way I can get it now. I've changed the DNS pointers already and the site now points to the new server.

The website's files are there in the old server and if I put an 'A'record (xx.xx.xx.xx/~myusername) the new server displays the old website which is fine. But I don't know why, I get errors in mail delivery. So I cannot use it.

In short, what I'm asking is an alternative of 'A' record if there is anything like that.

Both servers use cPanel.

Comment: Ok, so the downvotes shows that there isn't any!

Comment: Lost password. Yup dog ate my homework

Comment: LOL. It's actually a client's (a company with around 200 people) and somebody hosted it long back. Good thing - they are not paying the server charges!

Comment: Why don't you ask the old hosting provider to reset the password? You can use `wget` to get a copy of output HTML and static files such as images and CSS, but getting hold of the source code is not so easy. And apparently you can't ask the *somebody* for it any more.

Comment: @ Ben Hillier: Actually, I don't need the source files. Just need to show the website in the new server.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can get the entire site duplicated on the new server, is to contact the old host and get the password reset or have them send you a backup.
The server-side scripts are not available by any other means, especially not by using client-available access points.

Answer (score 0):

best you can do until actually rewriting the dynamic content generation, is a static content mirror. wget can make a mirror for you, something like
`wget --recursive --mirror URL`

then again, if your website has no dynamic content, this would get a full copy (provided there's any links to it in the urls wget download)